# Selenium and BrowserMobProxy don't show and set browser referer in Java, how to it

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob-proxy

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String driverGoogleChromePath = "D:\\Project Doc\\Jar\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
        String refererurl = "http://www.iteye.com/";
        String hostAndPort = "112.91.159.66:3128";
        int port = 3128;
        //String host = "112.91.159.66";
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverGoogleChromePath);
        //start the proxy
        BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Referer",refererurl);
        proxy.addHeaders(headers);
        proxy.start(port);
        
        
        Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
        seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy(hostAndPort)
                     .setSslProxy(hostAndPort)
                     .setFtpProxy(hostAndPort);
        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions().merge(capabilities);
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.get("http://www.java1234.com/");
        proxy.stop();
        //driver.close();
    }
```

This is my java code, I have set the referer to use the .addHeaders, but when I run it, the browser didn't show the referer, why, how to do show this ?

selenium: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar
browser: browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcJRT.png)